# Reverting yum update

Tags: centos, yum, nvidia

I needed to update NVidia driver on a CentOS 6.9 and decided to update a bit more. So I did `sudo yum update` and rebooted. Unfortunately that caused problems with NVidia that were worse than before. I am able to login only remotely now, and discovered that:

```
FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Oh, I wish I didn't update! Is it possible to revert the latest `yum update`?

Comment: You updated the kernel, and current kernel is missing relevant/Key module to low-level interact with your Nvidia card. Formerly, with previous kernel, how did you provided the Nvidia kernel module? By some ready-made packages (rpm, deb, etc)? Or compiling the sources by yourself? In the end: reboot with previous kernel; or update the Nvidia packages; or recompile again from the sources.

Comment: Take a look here for possible resolution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/784392/issues-with-nvidia-graphics-driver-and-cuda-after-apt-get-upgrade

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use `yum history`, and then `yum history undo <id of your update>` See more info in [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069).